# Ajax Get plus jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ejs

I have a little function to get an array asynchronously. I get the response and this all works, the only thing which doesn't, is the appending from the child. I don't know if this works like this, I tried, but it didn't work.

```
function getFiles(e, uname){
    $.get({
        url: `http://myurl/files/${uname}?dir=${e.id}`,
        success(response){
          for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
            $(`#${e.id}`).append('<div class="collapsible-body"><a href="/files/'+uname+'/download/'+response[i]+'">'+response[i]+'</a></div>');
             // $(`#${e.id}`).append("HELLO");
          }
        },
        error(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
```

It would be really nice if anyone has an answer. I am a bit new at JavaScript/ Thanks. If it is to unclear, please comment.

HTML/EJS:

```
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <% for(let i = 0; i < directories.length; i++){ %>
      <li id="<%= directories[i] %>" onclick="getFiles(this,'<%= user.username %>')">
        <div class="right" style="margin: 15px 10px 0 0"><a href="<%= user.username%>/bills/<%= directories[i] %>">Rechnung</a></div>
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">card_travel</i><%= directories[i] %></div>

      </li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup and the Javascript you're using to call getFiles? It would seem that e.id isn't referenced correctly.

Additionally, did the commented out line work correctly? `// $('#${e.id}').append("HELLO");`?

Comment: Post your markup structure

Comment: Need to provide a [mcve] .

Comment: What do ``console.log($(`#${e.id}`));`` and ``console.log($(`#${e.id}`).html());`` after appending reveal?

Comment: Here i added the html/ejs part, i hope this is enough. Gimme a sec, i will look @Xufox

Comment: Okay lol, the first one i get "Object [ li#test.active ]" and second i get "<div class="right" style="margin: 15px 10px 0 0"><a href="admin/bills/test">Rechnung</a></div>
              <div class="collapsible-header active"><i class="material-icons">card_travel</i>test</div>
"

Comment: Are both of these logs inside the `for` loop? If your HTML isn’t appended, `response.length` could likely be `0`. What does `console.log(response)` reveal, etc.?

Comment: response.length = 2. Console.log gives: "Array [ "Download.jpg", "Download_1.jpg" ]"

Comment: And If i put it in the forloop i get this twice: " Object [ li#test.active ] "

Comment: Does it work if you try a simple ID? Like `<li id="<%= 'dir' + i %>"...`?

Comment: Okay it works now. I had to trippleclick the button, thanks for the help. :)